# Connecting two SDRs together for one to act as a signal generator

Tags: software-defined-radio

If I have two SDRs like the BladeRF and I want to use one as a signal generator and connect them together do I have to attenuate the connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the specifications of the particular hardware, but in most cases **yes, you must use an attenuator.** Specifically, you want to compare the *maximum transmit power* (how much power the transmitter can produce) to the *maximum receive power* (the incoming power above which the receiver will be damaged).

Unfortunately, at a glance the bladeRF web site doesn't give these specifications, so **for the purposes of this answer I'll use the published figures for the [HackRF One](https://github.com/mossmann/hackrf/wiki/HackRF-One) instead,** but you’ll have to obtain the specs for your own hardware. The maximum transmit power in that case is given as 15 dBm (decibels relative to one milliwatt; i.e. 31 milliwatts). The maximum receive power is given as -5 dBm. Since we have them in the form of decibels, we can subtract the latter from the former to conclude there is a **20 dB** gap.

This means that for this example you should use an attenuator of **at least** 20 dB to avoid hardware damage. You may need even more attenuation than that to avoid distortion of the received signal, as the point of hardware damage is likely above the point of [clipping](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/2479/76).

You *could* use less attenuation by configuring your devices properly. For example, you can decrease transmit amplifier gain or send lower-amplitude samples, and you can also decrease or shut off receive amplification. But this is running the risk of hardware damage due to software misconfiguration — do you really want to take that chance? (However, using transmit power controls to avoid clipping on the receive side or to simulate a weaker signal is reasonable.)

For my own testing purposes, I am using a 0-80 dB manually-variable attenuator I picked up at a flea market. I find it quite useful and recommend you obtain a similar device if you can (new ones can be fairly expensive, however).

---

While you asked about software-defined radios, everything here is applicable to any other type of radio. Two notes on the subject:

- For higher-power transmitters, transmit power may be given in watts. Convert to dBm, $10\cdot\log_{10}\left(\tfrac{P}{0.001 W}\right)$, and remember that transmit power may be poorly calibrated and exceed the specified value.
- If your receiver does not have maximum receive power specs, you can start with sensitivity specs instead; you'll want to apply *more* than that signal, but how much more is needed until the signal is adequately received will have to be determined by experiment. This is where a *variable* attenuator is handy.